# Is it possible to fix a skate's cracked toe cap?

Tags: equipment, ice-hockey

A few weeks ago, in the dressing room after a game of ice hockey, I noticed that my right skate's toe cap got cracked. Being a defenseman, I probably blocked a shot that hit a weak point or something, and a small chunk of plastic is now missing from the skate's hard toe cap. Over the next couple of games, a crack grew outwards and across the toe cap, and I can now slightly see into the boot.

I'm obviously worried that this is unsafe, since another shot might break it and hit my toes, but I've also noticed that the boot has lost some structural integrity and flexes a lot more as I skate, which is not very good when it comes to skating hard and making sudden stops.

I'm wondering if anyone might know how I can fix this, or if it's really hopeless and I'll need to buy a new pair of skates. The skates themselves are no longer under warranty, but they're less than 3 years old, which makes the situation quite frustrating.

Comment: shoe goo. Maybe a hot glue gun? perhaps layers of shoe goo with some kind of cloth layered with goo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, I'd say you probably need to bite the bullet and get new skates. Every possible fix I can think of is a lot of work for very little reward...

If you have a [Play it again sports](http://www.playitagainsports.com/) anywhere near you, I'd recommend them for skates. I've gotten some lightly used skates there before for half of retail and I've been very happy with them.

Comment: Yeah, I figured as much, but it was worth a shot. There's a Play It Again Sports a few minutes away from my home, and it's the first place I visited because I would buy all my skates secondhand there for reasonable prices as a kid. But now I have size 14 feet and it's hard to find used skates any bigger than 11's...

Answer (score 0):

Use Pro Guard Toe Protector. You can buy it at most sporting good stores. It comes with its own brush, let each application dry completely before applying the next coat. 3-4 coats should do it. It dries to a hard, plastic like finish.